# Connecting to relay via GPIO not working

Tags: gpio

This may be more suited towards the Elec engineering SE, but thought I'd ask here as I'm working with the Pi.

I recently picked up this [relay board](http://skpang.co.uk/catalog/4ch-relay-board-kit-for-raspberry-pi-quick2wire-compatible-p-1200.html), and soldered it all together using [their guide](http://skpang.co.uk/blog/archives/753), however it seems not to be working, that is when I run `i2cdetect y - 1` it doesn't show anything in the 0x20 cell, which I think means the relay isn't connecting to the pi?

How do I go about debugging what the problem could be? I presume I'll have to start testing individual components to see if any of them have blown? Can that be done on the board itself, or will I have to un-solder the components?

If it impacts at all, when I first connected the pi to the relay via the ribbon cable, I accidentally connected it upside down (the red-strip was not at the top of the pi, where the 5v pin is)

Comment: You give almost no details of what you have done, so it is hard to help.
I gather it is using i2c Have you enabled this?
`i2c-bcm2708` is blacklisted in `/etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf`

Comment: @Milliways apologies, I've updated the description with a link to the guide I followed, but yes, I did comment out the bcm module from the black list.

Comment: Looking at the schematic, putting the connector upside down should be no problem (besides not working of course). Does `i2cdetect y - 1` show anything? Did you check the dip-swithes? Could you post a picture of the assembled board? Maybe some component is placed wrong. You can certainly test the board manually. I could give you some pointers if you need (do you have a multimeter?).

Comment: The guide says `i2cdetect -y 1`, not `i2cdetect y -1`. Are you sure you typed that in correctly?